# Vue Cli 3 vue.config.js no autoOpenBrowser option

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I created a project using @vue/cli 3 and attempted to add the autoOpenBrowser option and received the following error. So, I gather that this option is no longer available?

*ERROR  WebpackDevServerOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. webpack-dev-server has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'autoOpenBrowser'. These properties are valid:
   object { hot?, hotOnly?, lazy?, bonjour?, host?, allowedHosts?, filename?, publicPath?, port?, socket?, watchOptions?, headers?, logLevel?, clientLogLevel?, overlay?, progress?, key?, cert?, ca?, pfx?, pfxPassphrase?, requestCert?, inline?, disableHostCheck?, public?, https?, contentBase?, watchContentBase?, open?, useLocalIp?, openPage?, features?, compress?, proxy?, historyApiFallback?, staticOptions?, setup?, before?, after?, stats?, reporter?, logTime?, noInfo?, quiet?, serverSideRender?, index?, log?, warn? }*

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 4020,
    autoOpenBrowser: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Create **vue.config.js** file at root level and add your code in this file. Running the command **npm run serve** will automatically open your application in browser.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    open: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Duh, it was the open option... I was confusing the config/index.js file with webpack.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 4020,
    open: true
  }
}
```